# Resource loading fails when loading class is called from test

Tags: java, maven, jar, testng

I have two Maven modules `A` and `B` where the former depends on the latter. The JAR of `B` includes a resource from `B`'s `src/main/resources`. `A` has a test class (based on TestNG) that accesses some class from `B`. This class is the one loading the already mentioned resource using `getResourceAsStream(…)`.

When I execute the test in `A`, it fails indicating that the resource that the class in `B` requires cannot be found. More specifically, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream(…)` is accessed:

```
InputStream in = DetectorFactory.class.getResourceAsStream(pathToResource);
// in == null
```

The resource is definitely included in `B`'s JAR. Why can't the class in `B` load the resource when it is called from the test in `A`?

Comment: The method `getResourceAsStream` exists in type `Class` and in type `ClassLoader`. Please add more code showing what exactly you call. Especially in case of using a class loader, it is essential to tell us how you retrieve the class loader. I assume the problem being there.

Comment: What is your testng runner ? Ide or maven in command line ?

Comment: The test is run with `mvn test` on the command line. I've added a code snippet that shows how the resource is loaded in the Java code.

Comment: Do you reproduce the issue with another runner? Is the test working in your ide?

Comment: No, the same thing happens from Eclipse.